# Git with libsecret throws Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY

Tags: linux, git, authentication, credentials

I'm running a server with CentOS7 . I have installed git, libsecret and libsecret-dev. Pointed git to use the libsecret credential.helper but i get this error:

```
CRITICAL **: could not connect to Secret Service: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
```

I did not find any helpful documentation about this. I do not have D-Bus installed and i don't even have X11 running as this is a server and is managed purely through ssh.

I installed dbus after that, and still doesn't work. Does it require X11? That seems stupid since git does not require it so why make a credential helper for it that does.

Note: i can't change from https to ssh and use keys.

Comment: libsecret requires D-Bus, and D-Bus without X11 cannot be automatically started. You have to start it manually using `dbus-launch`.

Comment: @phd well that's the thing. i installed dbus and it does not recognize the command dbus-launch.

Comment: [dbus-launch is in the dbus-x11 package](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=172231)